# What is the difference between ADC single conversion mode and free running mode in ATmega32A?

Tags: adc, avr

Can someone explain this to me as I don't get what's written in this section of datasheet
A piece code written in C showing the difference would be great too . 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Single conversion** means, you trigger the conversion and it is done once. When the conversion is finished you have one result and the ADC is not doing anything more (not without a new conversion start trigger).

**Free running mode** means, the ADC is automatically starting a new conversion each time the last one finished. You don't have to retrigger the ADC in this mode.

I'm not sure what kind of code you want so see here, you can do all kinds of weird and wonderful stuff.

Comment: A simple code discussing free running mode is what I want , just to know how things really work . I'm pretty familiar with single conversion mode and I've written many projects using it .

Comment: Set the bits in the ADC configuration register for free running mode and then you can always have a recent result available in the high/low ADC result registers. Based on the ADC frequency you'll know the oldest the sample can possibly be, check the conversion complete flag also. You don't want to read the results while the ADV is simultaneously attempting to write them.